# Can I query Logs Explorer directly from a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For a monitoring project I'm using Logs Router to send log data to BigQuery Table so I can then query the BigQuery table from cloud functions. Would it be possible to directly query Log Explorer from Cloud Functions? (i.e not having to replicate my logs to BigQuery?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. You even have [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#list_log_entries) for that. However, keep in mind that, by default, your logs are kept only 30 days. It could be enough, or not, depending on your use case.

You can create custom [log bucket](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets), with a different retention period, or sing the logs in BigQuery.

The main advantage of BigQuery if the capacity to join the logs data with other data in BigQuery, to perform powerful analytics computation. But still depends on your use case.